# In Flutter, how does one preview a document?

Tags: flutter, document, preview

I've searched through DuckDuckGo/Google, stackOverflow, Github and flutter documentation and plugin repository, but I can't seem to find the answer to this simple question:

How can I, having a document's file uri, display a preview thumbnail for it as an Image?

Comment: If you are interested in something similar to whatsapp chat file sharing, then here is a tip(though, its a guess, but tried and tested one!). Whatsapp uploads the file to the server and generates a thumbnail there. Now that thumbnail is returned in response and added to the chat. You can easily verify this in whatsapp

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could read the file as a String and then get the first 500 characters with a substring from it:

```
// File path
final file = await File.fromUri(uri);

// Read the file
String contents = await file.readAsString();

// Get first 500 characters or how many you want
String preview = contents.substring(0, 500);

// Display in widget
Text(preview);
```

Don't forget to put it into a [StatefulWidget](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/) and update the state when the file was finished reading. Also see Flutters [File](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html) class.

Comment: thanks @Bostrot, that is a good idea, for a text file, unfortunately text files are rare documents, these days, most of them are PDF, and office documents